# How to print the best answer field?

Tags: 7

I am use the [Best Answer](https://www.drupal.org/project/best_answer) module. I customize the answer template, `node-answer.tpl.php` and I want to print best answer field,add

No output result, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Best Answer](https://www.drupal.org/project/best_answer) module extends the **7.x-3.x** version of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of it). However, this module has been integrated as a sub-module of the **7.x-4.x** release of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers). This release also has the new theming stuff (if you enable the brand new `answers_theme` sub-module) as in this sample screenprint of it:

[image]

Note **the checkbox** in the bottom-left of it (shown to the left of the accepted answer), which I believe is the equivalent of the ***best answer field*** that your question is about.

So unless you have good reasons to continue with the **7.x-3.x**, I strongly recommend you to first upgrade to the **7.x-4.0-rc2** release of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers), which might possibly obsolete what you're trying to achieve.

Even though the 7.x-4.x release is not yet an official release, it is fairly stable/functional, and only has a few more minor glitches to be resolved. The next release that will become available, will include the newest features as you can see in the [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/module/answers) already. More important: if you're just starting with the module, you won't have to "migrate" from 3.x in the future (some type of migration will be needed, which is still an open issue for now).

### Try the most recent 7.x-4.x release

To experience it yourself, try out a demo of it. Here are the steps to do so:

- Head over to [the demo site](http://simplytest.me/project/answers).
- Just accept the defaults to create a sandbox demo site (make sure you're using the most recent 7.x-4.x release). Then hit the create sandbox button, and wait for the process to complete. Make sure you also enable the ***Answers Theme*** (sub-module of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers), new as of 7.x-4.x).
- Create at least 1 question using either the "*Add content*" menu link and then selecting "Question", or just enter relative path `/node/add/question`. And complete the title and body of the question.
- After you save the question, you'll see the question that's created (in view mode). And below the question, you should see "No answers yet." (since you just completed posting the question). And then there is the "Your Answer" form right below that. That is the form you can use to post an answer to the question.
- If you then use that (answer) form to post your answer, and also save that, the (first) answer is shown below the question, and below that answer there is now the "Your Answer" form again (to allow for posting an additional answer).
- Use the ***Questions*** tab (or enter relative path `/questions`, to get a list (a tabular display) of all existing questions so far (there should be at least one if you completed the previous step).

### Demo site

Have a look at the [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/module/answers) of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module. This link shows various menu options within the block with title ***Answers Menu***, i.e.:

- **Questions** (= a view):

  - **All**: of all existing questions (= default tab).
  - **Answered**: all questions which have a "best" (= accepted) answer (= sub-tab).
  - **Unanswered**: all questions which do not yet have a "best" (= accepted) answer (= sub-tab).
- **Answers** (= a view): lists all existing answers for any of the existing questions and which does not (yet) have any submenu options (implemented as tabs).
- **Rankings** (= a view): contains a list of users with their actual ranking (= reputation points implemented via user points), and with each user a link to either the questions or answers from that user.
- **Ask Question**: to post a new question (the equivalent of `node/add/question`), which is only shown for authenticated users though.

These [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) also use the [dataTables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) format, but you could easily replace that with any views display format you'd want. And because of the search box that comes with dataTables, there is no need for extra menu links to search within questions, answers or rankings.

These new/enhanced views were created starting from the 7.x-4.x-rc2 release of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers), and will be included in the next release of it also (together with various other enhancements not yet visible in the demo site).

Comment: This might be the [Best Answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221804/how-to-print-the-best-answer-field#221810) I have ever seen.

Comment: Merci for the kudos @NoSssweat ... But I think there is even a better [Best Answer](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/answers/tree/answers_best_answer?h=7.x-4.x) ... ie one of the Answer's sub-modules included in the 7.x-4.x release